# Making reverse-incremental-search in terminal easier using comments

Tags: command-line, bash, bash-history

When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> in terminal this leads to use the reverse-incremental-search mode.

The reverse-i-search lets you search for previous commands in your terminal, but this can get confusing when you use the same command with different options and become exhausting to search for your needed command.

How can I distinguish between the commands easily, or mark a particular command?

Comment: For the downvoter, it's better to say why to downvote?!

Comment: Perhaps you want to make the question a question and not put one of many solutions already in the question title. ;) (I did not downvote though, but in the current state I can't upvote either.)

Comment: This post is just to help newbies and it's not rally a question for me since i know how to move around the exhausting search in ctrl+r... but i thought this will help others

Answer (score 7):

`#` in some configuration files and programming languages marks comments and is excluded from execution.

Run a command and then create a hashtag using # of the command so that we can find it later.

```
some-command #mycommand
```

for example:

```
sudo dmidecode | grep -A 9 "System Information" #sysInfo
```

Now I create a hash tag `#sysInfo` for the command `sudo dmidecode | grep -A 9 "System Information"` which is used to show system information.

Now search for the hash tag in reverse-i-search (press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>), in the terminal and type `#sysInfo`.

You may create as many hash tags for every command and find it later using reverse-i-search.

***Note:*** hashtag used here is not really the same concept as we know in social media. This word is just used to clarify and make it easy for newbies to understand the answer.

[source](http://www.tecmint.com/linux-commandline-chat-server-and-remove-unwanted-packages/)

Comment: "hashtag" really? that's just a Bash comment.

Comment: yes i know it's just a comment but it's just a workaround for newbies to understand

Comment: I understand that you're trying to make things easier, but the concept of comments is pretty easy to understand ('the terminal ignores anything to the right of a hash symbol' or something along those lines), and using 'hashtag' seems like it would lead to more confusion if anything